# Entry validation stop working when triggered in specific situations

Tags: python, linux, windows, tkinter

I have an application I made. It works fine except for one thing. I want certain labels to get different background color depending on content of an Entry widget and if content matches, the content of the Entry should be deleted so that more data can be entered. I made an example application which has the same problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import Tkinter as tk

class Frontend:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.vcmd = (self.frame.register(self.validate), '%P')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.frame, vcmd=self.vcmd, validate='key')
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text='Foo', bg='green')
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self.frame, text='Bar', bg='green')

        self.frame.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.label1.pack()
        self.label2.pack()

        self.entry.focus()

    def validate(self, inputstring):
        if re.match(r'^foo$', inputstring):
            self.label1.config(bg='red')
            self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        elif re.match(r'^bar$', inputstring):
            self.label2.config(bg='red')
            self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        elif re.match(r'^delete$', inputstring):
            self.label1.config(bg='green')
            self.label2.config(bg='green')
            self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        return True

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Frontend()
    root.start()
```

The problem is that after the first time something matches and the content of the Entry widget is deleted. The validation command stops working. I have a suspicion it's the fact that I am deleting the content of the Entry which is causing this problem, but I am not sure. I have confirmed that this problem exist on Linux hosts and Windows hosts.

Anyone have an Idea why the validation stops doing what it is suppose to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation isn't designed to support the modification of the widget during validation. From the [official documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M7):

> The
>   validate option will also set itself to none when you edit the entry
>   widget from within either the validateCommand or the invalidCommand.
>   Such editions will override the one that was being validated.

It goes on to say that if you wish to edit the entry inside the validation that you use `after_idle` to reset the validate attribute once validation is complete. It would look something like this:

```
self.entry.after_idle(lambda: self.entry.configure(validate='key'))
```